# Group by and take 1 of class object in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public static IQueryable<ProBE> GetAllPol()
        {
            ConnectionString CS = new ConnectionString();
            var pol = (from pol in CS.pols
                            select new ProBE
                            {
                                Id = pol.Id,
                                Name = pol.Name,
                                Weight = pol.Weight,
                                EnID = pol.EnID,
                                PolID = pol.PolID
                            }).GroupBy(c=>c.PolID).Take(1);
            return pol;
        }
```

Above is my code which binds to Devexpress grid. I will be having 2 or more entries in DB in `CS.pols` table in `DB`. I want to group by by `PolID` as only this field will remain same across versions. I want to `group by` it and `take 1` . I am getting an error saying cannot convert `IQueryAble` to `ProBE`. Please help as to how can I get the desired data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem, since you are doing a `GroupBy` at the end it will return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<T>>` so that will never convert to `IQueryable<ProBE>`. So you need to group it first and then project the same.

Next problem is with `Take`, it returns `IEumerable<T>` but you need just the first item after grouping so use `FirstOrDefault` instead:-

```
var pol = (from pol in CS.pols
           group pol by pol.PolID into g
           let firstgroupedPol = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault()
           select new ProBE
                 {
                   Id = firstgroupedPol != null ? firstgroupedPol.Id : 0,
                   Name = firstgroupedPol != null ? firstgroupedPol.Name : "",
                   //similarily others
                   PolID = g.Key
                 });
```

Comment: Tahnks it worked. But I have 2 records of a single Name with different versions. I want the latest version which I can get by the Id(Latest Primary key). How can i achieve that. Now the solution that you provided gives me first(old version record). Please help.

Comment: @user2998990 - You can simply order it by id in descending order. Check my update.

Comment: you are a life saver Rahul. Thanks a ton